# Short URL services not working properly

Tags: url-shortening

any idea why short URL services fail very often?

Mozilla shows a "Problem loading page" error page:

```
Server not found. Firefox can't find the server at www.t.co.
```

This is especially true for `t.co` for example.
If I refresh continuously over a large period of time, it will eventually redirect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`t.co` is run by Twitter and like twitter.com itself it suffers from overloading. The same could apply to other popular services.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Although that's hardly an excuse on their part.